# Getting python to recognize my internet filter's ssl certificate

Tags: python, ssl-certificate

I have an internet filter, Netspark, with provides a `.crt` file that contains the server's certificate information to make itself into a trusted certificate source. (I'm probably not expressing this correctly.) This seems to work on web browsers. Now I am trying to load HTTPS sites with Python's `ssl` library,

```py
context = ssl.create_default_context(capath='www_netspark_com.crt')
urlopen('https://www.example.com', context=context)
```

and I get an error:

`ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1002)`

Any suggestions as to why Python has this issue but not the browser, and/or how to fix it?

Comment: Hope you need to use cafile instead of capath to give reference to your certificate file. Please [check]https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.create_default_context

Comment: @KJG, that has the same result.

Comment: Hope your certificate is in PEM or DER format. Also try including purpose=Purpose.SERVER_AUTH
(or) instead of addind certificate to your program at runtime, include this certificate in Python cacert.pem file. You can find its location by
import certifi
print(certifi.where())
In this method your will be adding certificate permanently to your python environment. If your script suceeds and if you want to use it in anotherr system, again you need to import the certificate in pem file.
PEM file is just a text file

Comment: The code presented in this question is *incorrect*; `capath` must point to a **directory**. If you want to point at a **file**, you need to use the `cafile` option. These options are documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.load_verify_locations). It would also be helpful if you could share the `www_netspark_com.crt` certificate in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the `ssl` library needs the certificate in `pem` format. [(Source)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.load_verify_locations)

I was able to convert the `.crt` file with the bash command:

`openssl x509 -in www_netspark_com.crt -out netspark.pem`

Then putting `netspark.pem` into `cafile=` (instead of `capath=`), the code works.